# Looking for a code sample or "template" for an EF Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, repository-pattern

I'm looking for a good Entity Framework repository code sample or template.

Comment: More detail would lead to a better answer.

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for a good example of using EF with the repository pattern?

Comment: Yes, with the repository pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here you go.](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/02/27/chapter-5-understanding-models.aspx)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Stephen Walther usually has good tutorials. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good implementation of Generic-Repository, Specification and Unit of Work patterns in the [NCommon](http://www.codeplex.com/ncommon) open-source project on Codeplex.  You can use subversion to [download the source](https://ncommon.svn.codeplex.com/svn) to your local machine and build it.

The Author's Blog:  http://www.codeinsanity.com/